# Laravel - pass id token to closure from route

Tags: laravel, routes

Inside a routes closure in routes.php, such as

```
Route::get('test/{id}', function()
{  
    // do stuff
});
```

Is it possible to access the token {id} inside the closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{id}` will be passed as first argument to the closure:

```
Route::get('test/{id}', function($id)
{  
    echo $id;
});
```